# WordPress Manual SELECT MySQL based on postmeta column value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm building a custom PHP page for my WordPress project. My project is about events information. So I'm creating a page to search for events based on date range.

event table

```
post_id  | title        |
25       | Marathon Run |
```

postmeta table

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key  | meta_value
1       | 25      | StartDate | 2016-12-25 00:00
2       | 25      | EndDate   | 2016-12-26 00:00
```

WordPress stores data in a complex way as the tables above. "StartDate" and "EndDate" are stored as value in `meta_key` column and the actual value of "StartDate" and "EndDate" are stored in `meta_value` column.

I find it hard to filter like the usual structure I always work on for example:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE startdate <= $startdate AND enddate >= $enddate
```

How to write the MySQL statement to filter date range for this kind of structure? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to join on the events table (on post_id) and then  filter on the meta_key (for StartDate and EndDate) and then check if it is in the correct range.

See below;

```
SELECT * FROM events JOIN postmeta ON events.post_id = postmeta.post_id WHERE (meta_key = 'StartDate' AND meta_value <= $startdate) AND (meta_key = 'EndDate' AND meta_value >= $enddate)
```

Comment: meta_key is in postmeta table while events are in another table.

Comment: Please provide schema examples for each of the tables you've mentioned

Comment: Try that, I've added a join statement so that you can select the events and the postmeta data

Comment: Nope MySQL returned an empty result set